# How to define and call a variable defined in a Makefile

Tags: r, variables, makefile

This maybe something trivial but I don't know how to do it.
I have a makefile that includes several R and Bash scripts that can be called by make to execute. I declare a variable (project = ABC123) in the Makefile and would like to use it in the R & bash scripts so that I don't have to declare the variable in each of the script. I am able to do this for the Bash scripts by exporting the variable and calling it in the bash script. However, I do not know how to call this variable in the R script.

Makefile:

```
project = ABC123
export project
make bashscript_1
make rscript_1
```

bashscript_1:

```
cat $project"_SampleList".csv
```

rscript_1:

```
read.csv(file = $project"_SampleList".csv)
```

The Bash script is working as expected but the R script does not recognize the variable unless I declare it in this script. Can someone help me? Appreciate your help.

Here is my Makefile and R script:

**Makefile:**

```
VAR=foo
scripts = /data/resources/scripts/

all:
    @Rscript -e 'var<-"${VAR}"' -e "source('foo.R')"

.PHONY: all

foo:
    Rscript $(scripts)foo.R
```

**R script** (foo.R. The script is saved in path "/data/resources/scripts/")

`print(sprintf("Hello, %s",var))`

I am calling the R script by using make foo. I haven't made any changes to what you suggested. Once I have this working, I think it will be easier for to tailor it to my needs. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Makefile`:

```
VAR=foo

all:
    @Rscript -e 'var<-"${VAR}"' -e "source('foo.r')"

.PHONY: all
```

The `Rscript` can run R-scripts with `-e`.

The first `-e` is used to declare the `var` variable (its value from `Makefile`'s `VAR`). The next `-e` load the main `R` program (`foo.r`). If you use `-e` in `Rscript` you can't run R-file with `Rscript foo.r` so will need use `-e source(...)`.

The `foo.r`:

```
print(sprintf("Hello, %s",var))
```

The output of `make`:

```
$ make
[1] "Hello, foo"
```

I hope it's clear :)

Comment: Can you please explain? Sorry, I'm pretty new to scripting and cannot follow.

Comment: @SureshSelvaraj now?

Comment: Thanks. Trying to digest. Looks like it may work. Will check it out and respond. Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you don't understand something, ask!

Comment: Thank for adding details but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I get the following error.                                                                                                                       "Error in as.character(function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use)  : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Calls: print -> sprintf
Execution halted
Makefile:268: recipe for target 'foo' failed
make: *** [foo] Error 1"

Comment: Could you please share your `R`-file and `Makefile` (in your question, you can edit)? Without them I can't help you.

Comment: Sure, here is my Makefile & R file.                                                                 
`VAR=foo
scripts = /data/resources/scripts/
all:
 @Rscript -e 'var<-"${VAR}"' -e "source('foo.R')"

.PHONY: all
 
foo:
 Rscript $(scripts)foo.R`

Comment: I think I got it now. It is working now but can you help me with the syntax for reading a csv file with the variable as its name?                                                                      
foo.R:

Comment: And what is your `R`-file? The error is in your `R`-script. Please edit your question because in comments hard to see the file contents.

Comment: csv-file: do you know `read.csv`? You can pass variable to `file` option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix this and get it working on the local computer. I will accept your answer. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just one more question. I have more than 1 variable to pass on to the R script from the makefile. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you should use more `-e`: `Rscript -e 'var1<-"${VAR1}"' -e 'var2<-"${VAR2}"' ...`